The order of a linear profinite group over commutative profinite ring
Recall that one can define the order of a profinite group using the notion of supernatural number. Let $A$ be a commutative profinite ring and let $G$ be a topologically finitely generated closed subgroup of ${\rm GL}_n(A)$. Is it true that the order of the profinite group $G$ (as a supernatural number) is divisible only by finitely many primes? Note that it's true when $A$ is a complete Noetherian local ring with finite residue field of characteristic $p>0$ because ${\rm GL}_n(A)$ contains an open pro-$p$ group in this case. For example, $A=\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the ring of $p$-adic integers.
